# Android WebView resolving URL occasionally results in multiple hits with different user agents

Tags: android, url, webview, user-agent

Hope you guys can offer me some advice.

I'm using a WebView component in a wrapper application. It has been observed that when hitting a certain URL multiple hits are made to the same page in quick succession but passing different user agents.

For example:
- LOAD URL TO WEBVIEW

- RECEIVE PAGE HIT REQUEST WITH Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; GT-S6310N Build/JZO54K) 2014-02-26 10:35:57.523
- RECEIVE PAGE HIT REQUEST WITH Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-gb; GT-S6310N Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 2014-02-26 10:35:57.603

It should be noted that I am calling setUserAgentString on WebSettings to supply the user agent string.

```
final WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

final String strUserAgent = mWebSettings.getUserAgentString();

if (strUserAgent != null) {
    mWebSettings.setUserAgentString(strUserAgent);
}
```

Is there a rational explanation for why this would only hit the page once most of the time, but occasionally hit it twice with different user agents as in the example provided?

Thanks for any insight you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the wrapper is requesting data from the URL using the HTTPClient before passing it to the WebView.